# Bash, what does this redirect command do

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a script that looks something like this:

`ruby foo.rb > log.out 2> error.log < /dev/null &`

In this case, i understand that STDOUT is redirecting to log.out and that 2> is redirecting the STDERR file descriptor to error.log. What's confusing me here is what comes after the STDERR redirect to error.log is the `< /dev/null` except. What exactly is being redirected `error.log` here, is it STDERR or /dev/null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case the `<` indicates INPUT redirection.  So the input to the `ruby` command is coming from `/dev/null` (i.e. no input).